# Do I need to delete a texture after calling SDL_DestroyTexture()?

Tags: c++, sdl2

Let's suppose I have this texture:

```
SDL_Texture* txt = IMG_LoadTexture(renderer, "path");
/* various code */
SDL_DestroyTexture(txt);
delete txt; // <- Is this part really necessary? Doesn't SDL_DestroyTexture() does it already?
```

Since there's not a lot of documentation about SDL, I haven't found an answer to my question on my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

SDL2 is a C library, and since C has no `delete` keyword, it wouldn't make sense here.

C allocates memory using `malloc` and friends, but usually C libraries take the approach of managing the memory for you, so if there are functions like `SDL_DestroyTexture`, you can assume that they also free the allocated memory.

Comment: It might help mentioning that resource creation and resource destruction functions normally come in pairs, and mentioning the common ones.

Answer (score 2):

```
SDL_DestroyTexture(txt);
```

should clean up and then free the memory used by the texture. However you will be left with a dangling pointer so be sure to deal with that.

```
txt = NULL //if using C
txt = nullptr //if using C++
```

*(Unless you're **really** sure the variable won't ever be used again before you leave the scope)*
Without doing this if the pointer variable is used again before being reassigned it will likely cause a crash or a bug.

Comment: I'm sorry, even if your answer isn't wrong, it isn't really relevant to the question because I asked something a little bit different...